# Write to Excel with VBScript in Windows Service

Tags: c#, vba, excel, vbscript

I'm trying to start VBScript called `sample.vbs` using Windows Service but I couldn't do that. When I open Task Manager I can see Microsoft ® Windows Based Script Host opened, Excel opened, but that's it, nothing happens after that.

When I do the same with Console Applicatin everything works perfectly.

Here is my vbs file:

```
SET objExcelApp = CREATEOBJECT("Excel.Application")
WITH objExcelApp
    .DefaultSaveFormat = xlWorkbookNormal
    .DisplayAlerts = FALSE
    .Workbooks.Open "C:\SoftwareARGE\data.xlsx"
    .DisplayFullScreen = FALSE
    .Visible = FALSE
END WITH
SET objExcelSheet = objExcelApp.Worksheets(1)
objExcelSheet.Cells(1 , 1) = "some data"
objExcelSheet.SaveAs strExcelAppenFile
objExcelApp.Application.Quit
```

And here is how I call vbs from C#:

```
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo = 
new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c sample.vbs")
{

      RedirectStandardOutput = true,
      WorkingDirectory = "some path", //actually it's like C:\..

      UseShellExecute = false,

      CreateNoWindow = true
};

System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process()
{
      StartInfo = procStartInfo
};
proc.Start();

proc.WaitForExit();// <---- Can't move forward in Windows Service
```

I don't think the problem's reason is permissions of the Windows Service, because I'm runnig it as admin user.

Any help would be awesome.

Best regards,
Ogün ADSAY.

Comment: Have you declared a contant variable in vbs for *xlWorkbookNormal*? Obviously it doesnt know what that means.

Comment: No, I didn't, but I don't think that's the problem, because vbs file work from console application, but doesn't work from windows service.

Comment: I'm suprised it works without you setting a value for `xlWorkbookNormal`. If you were to add `Option Explicit` (which is a good idea), it would fail. Why not just put your code directly in C#? _or_ just call the VBS as a scheduled task?

Comment: I should call the VBS from windows service. Because there is a client side of the project for customers can manage the time of tasks etc. I couldn't understand the part you've said put the code directly in C#, it's already in C#?

Comment: What I mean is: take all that VBS code you've written, convert it to C# and put in your C# program. Now you only have one language to support. Alternatively, if you must keep using VBS and you need something that allows user to modify schedules etc., _use the windows scheduler_. Don't go and write a service. Why write a service when you can already do it?